# AS3 - Usage of external .AS

Tags: actionscript-3

I'ld like to use an external .AS in my project. 
How do I need to link to it to make it work? I always get this error:

> 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Stats.

This is the .AS file:
- https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats/master/src/net/hires/debug/Stats.as
- https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats

Thanks.

Comment: did you import Stats.as?

Comment: This is my code: `import net.hires.debug.Stats;
addChild(new Stats());` It's still not working with no specific error message. Ideas?

Comment: Are you making sure your program is looking for the src/ folder?

Comment: Can you please explain a little further what you mean?

Comment: As Jonatan Hedborg  stated did you include the net folder in your build path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the Flash Player only executes SWF files (compiled binary files). This is unlike JavaScript where the engine can dynamically load and execute source during runtime.

AS3 code *must* be compiled before-hand; this means you'll need all your source locally, or somehow accesible to the compiler so that it can produce the SWF.

Comment: Also make sure that wherever the code is called, the class is being imported: "import net.hires.debug.Stats"